# Can javascript cause 502 Bad Gateway Error?

Tags: javascript, php, nginx

Can javascript cause 502 Bad Gateway Error?

Sorry for this noob question. I have a website with Nginx and php-fpm. Sometimes I get 502 Bad Gateway error after submitting a contact form. I'm looking into other possibilities besides server side settings (Nginx, php-fpm etc.).

```
Submit form  -> process form -> display Thank You page.
```

On the Thank You page, I execute Marketo Javascript API to send data to Marketo. https://developers.marketo.com/javascript-api/forms/

```
<script src="//app-xyz.marketo.com/js/forms2/js/forms2.js"></script>
<form id="mktoForm_621"></form>
<script>
    MktoForms2.loadForm("//app-ab00.marketo.com", "785-UHP-775", 1057, function(form) {
    // Set the value of the Phone and Country fields
    form.vals({ "Phone":"555-555-1234", "Country":"USA"});
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, that could be possible. But as you haven't shared any PHP code, it's impossible to tell you why this happens

Comment: It's most probably an error on the server side that happens during the processing of your request. If that happens only sometimes you might check which data you're sending to the server before it crashes. That way it should be easy for you to debug what causes the problem.

Comment: 502 is a server error, not an issue of the browser. Javascript can only initiate a request to a server, which ends in 502, but it cannot _cause_ it.

Comment: @NicoHaase Let say there's no issue with the PHP code, the Thank you page opens and the javascript works behind the scene to submit data to another server which I have no control of and something wrong over there. I supposed I will have javascript error (like in the console) but there shouldn't be any 502 error, am I right?

Comment: @florian_ I coudn't debug anything on the server side so I'd like to know if there's any possibility that the javascript could have caused it.

Comment: @HonkderHase So you mean if the javascript was executed after the Thank You page showed up then there won't be any 502 error, am I right?

Comment: HTTP Responses starting 500-599 are server error responses[¹](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#server_error_responses). So, no. Since you're using JavaScript at the client-side it doesn't make sense that your JavaScript code would throw any 502 error. It must receive that error from the server as a response to your request.

Comment: A 502 indicates, that an intermediate server, like a gateway or a proxy, has lost the connection. It was not the last server, the application server, but a loadbalancer, a proxy or any other gateway between that last server and the client. So, when the request came in, all was good, but _before_ the response could been sent, the proxy dropped/lost the connection. The response will never arive at your browser, cause the gateway is gone. Maybe application took too long to calculate the response :)